# AngularJS component with $compile loses $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that loads some AngularJS (v1.2.16) components dynamically. It requests a list of components from a WebAPI, then loads the files it is told to, and finally uses `$compile` to compile the components.

However, the components lose their `$scope` after the initial load! If I have an `ng-click` event in the component, it flat out refuses to be fired!

This is my directive inside my main JS file:

```
var myApp = angular.module(.......);

myApp.directive('components', function($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $http.get('myapi/getListOfComponents').success(function(components) {

               var scripts = Array();
               var templates = Array();

               angular.forEach(components, function (component, key) {
                   if (component.JavaScript !== null) {
                       // This is the path to the JS file to dynamically load
                       scripts.push(widget.JavaScript);
                   }
               });

               // Load the JS file for all the components
               // I'm using the dynamic loader found here: https://github.com/ded/script.js (it's old, but it works)
               $script(scripts, function () {
                   angular.forEach(widgets, function (widget, key) {
                       templates.push(
                           // Get the raw HTML contents of the component
                           $http.get(widget.Template).success(function (componentHtmlContent) {
                               element.append('<div class="component">' + componentHtmlContent + '</div>');
                               $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                           }));
                   });
               });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And an example component's template:

```
<div ng-controller="myComponentController">
    <h2>{{MyHeading}} - {{MyInlineFunction()}} - {{SomeValue}}</h2>
    <button ng-click="MyClickFunction()">Button</button>
</div>
```

And the component's script

```
serviceWebApp.controllerProvider('myComponentController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.SomeValue = "Foo";

    $http.get('/myapi/getsomedata').success(function (data) {
        $scope.MyHeading = data;
    });

    $scope.MyInlineFunction = function() {
        return "SomeInlineValue";
    }

    $scope.MyClickFunction = function() {
        alert('Something was clicked');
    }
});
```

When the page loads, both `MyInlineFunction` and the `$http.get` are called just fine, and all the bindings in the template (`{{MyHeading}} - {{MyInlineFunction()}} - {{SomeValue}}`) get the correct values.

The button, on the other hand, refuses to work. `MyClickFunction` is never called.

I've also tried to look at the contents of that controller's scope using the following command in the browser developer console:

`angular.element($("div[ng-controller~='myComponentController']")).scope()`

The scope returned from this does **not** contain `SomeValue`, or the other values/functions defined in the scope.

So it seems that the `$compile` works only one time, and fails to keep track of the scope.

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is that you operate on the same scope for multiple controllers. They can overwrite each others `MyClickFunction` or whatever. It likely should be `$compile(element.contents())(scope.$new())`. If it's not the case, please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - a plunk would be fine.

Comment: Darnit! I tried to create a plunkr to demonstrate this, but I can, of course, get it to work there! I can't see what I must be doing wrong with my actual code, though, and I really don't want to share production code here. Catch-22.

Comment: I finally found out what was causing this. After the dynamic adding I did some juggling with the elements using jQuery. This apparently messed with AngularJS' internal state somehow and caused the components to lose the connection to their scopes. The solution was to do `$compile` at the very bottom, _after_ the jQuery juggling. Now my `ng-click` is called every time :) I'll close the question instead of deleting it, for future visitors.

Comment: Closing own question needs 5 votes. Probably a better option is a self-answer. Yes, a lot of weird things can happen when Angular is used together with jQuery, this efficiently voids the warranty. The use of $compile itself tells that something fishy may happen.

Comment: I noticed the vote requirement when I tried closing it. I'll try to rephrase the question and add an appropriate answer. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I also use jQuery to move around the elements in the DOM. When I move a component that had previously been initialized, it lost its connection to the scope.

Another thing I noticed when debugging was that the First component got initialized thrice, the second two times, and the third one time. (or "4,3,2,1" if there are four components). This is because `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` is inside the `foreach`, and each subsequent component will get loaded multiple times.

The solution was to move the recompilation to be below all the jQuery, while also moving it inside a block that is run when all HTML content has promised to be loaded.

A working Plunker can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGnGXb9N3SsoIUjJx5N4?p=preview